# Asp.net MVC - Open local files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tricky one.
Browser Security says "No".

Scenario:
Forms and Templates are used throughout the business, this can be word, excel or pdfs files.
We have a intranet system and I would like to offer users the ability to open files via this way. (not download).
However the browser has other ideas (which I understand why), however is their a work around?
to achieve this?

Comment: Define "open files."  All the web application can do is send the file to the client as a response.  What the client *does* with that file is up to the client.  The web application can *suggest* what should be done with it, usually by means of the `Content-Disposition` header.  How are you sending the file to the client?

Comment: I think the OP is wanting to be able to Open the file in Word for example and be able to click "Save" and have it publish back to the server.